# How to detect collision of two images?

Tags: objective-c, ios, collision-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate an end screen when two images collide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841279/how-to-generate-an-end-screen-when-two-images-collide)

how to generate an end screen when two images collide. I am making an app with a stickman you move with a very sensitive acceremeter. SO if it hits these spikes, (UIImages) it will generate the end screen. How do I make the app detect this collision and then generate an end screen.

Comment: -1 You asked the exact same question 2 hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView1.frame, imageView2.frame)) {
    // Do whatever it is you need to do.
}
```